# C Linux open source projects

Tags: c, linux

Sorry if this has been asked elsewhere. I am a C,Win32 developer and want to learn similar stuff in the linux world. What are  the best and easy opensource projects for learning similar stuff on Linux.

Like in C,Win32 world i want to start off with User space and onto advance stuff like internals,device drivers etc. I am interested in Non UI stuff. As i have a day job and work extensively on Windows i would like to see short little projects and contribute to them in free time.

Comment: Voting to close this question as this is a very vague and ambiguous question in which the OP did not state clearly enough and the answers given are not satisfying LinuxHungry's Post!

Answer (score 3):

The [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) are probably as low-level and as "Linux-ey" (that's not really a word, is it?) as it gets in user space. Not always easy-to-read code, but most of those sections are bugfixes of one kind or another. So, you'll learn about some pitfalls of modern unix-like systems on the way. That, and most of the basic [unix programming principles](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/).

As most utilities are very small, just trying to rewrite some only with the spec from the manpage should give you insights into Linux (or unix for that matter) no tutorial can offer.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Linux Device Drivers](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/) is freely available.  You can get a good overview of what's going on "under the hood" reading through that book.  It also has several examples of "virtual" device drivers that don't interact with actual hardware.  Follow the sample code and you can create things like a driver for `/dev/null`, `/dev/random`, etc without having to worry about hardware interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice would be to pick one and stick with it no matter how overwhelming it is, once you get your feet wet in it, enjoy... this is a $64,000 question -

- What specific areas of C/Win32 did you enjoy most?
- Was it hardware based?
- Writing drivers?

No one can answer that nor expect to pick the answer for you, **except** yourself....

- What was it that gave you a "high" in the Win32 C world...

Once you have that answer, then look for that alternative, somewhere, in the Open Source world....and relax, participate in IRC channels, forums, and engage.

You may have to re-learn using make/gcc toolchains and autotools in order to get your feet grounded...if you're comfortable with that... excellent... :)

Some will have their coding style and standards set down in stone... so pick the easy project that you feel you'll get a kick out of, and above all, **ENJOY**! :D

Comment: Whoever down-voted this question should post a comment into why that answer was not good enough! That OP question is too vague and only the OP can answer that [him|her]self... no point in asking us... Have voted to close the question as its too vague and ambiguous!

Comment: tommieb75: i edited my question again:)

Answer (score -1):

what are you interested in ?
The nice thing about linux is that the source for almost everything is available.

Comment: Get familiarity with linux development and debugging environments. Would like to do some little projects to learn about Linux internals mostly non UI stuff.